# MATLAB: Pricing a digital option, Monte Carlo vs. explicit integral formula?

Tags: matlab, montecarlo, numerical-integration, probability-density

I am stuck with the following problem using MATLAB:

Let Z be lognormally distributed such that ln Z has mean m and variance w. Let eta be a negative number and c a positive constant.

I am trying to compute the expected value (let I(Z<=c) denote the indicator function of the set (Z<=c))

E[Z^(eta+1) I(Z<=c)] = (1/sqrt(w)) integral_0^c x^(eta) phi((ln x - m)/sqrt(w)) dx,

where phi() denotes the probability distribution function of a standard normal random variable.

First thing I did was to simulate 10.000 trials of Z, set the entries of the vector with value >c to 0, raised to the power of (eta+1) and then calculated the mean. This should give me the MC estimate of the expected value.

```
ST = random('Lognormal', m,w_sq,10000,1);
hlp = zeros(10000,1);
hlp(ST<=2) = ST(ST<=2);
hlp(hlp>0) = hlp(hlp>0).^(eta1+1); % 0^(eta1+1) gives infinity
mean(hlp)
```

For the integral I used the following code

```
tmpp = integral(@(x) x.^(eta1) .* normpdf((log(x)-m)/sqrt(w_sq),0,c);
tmpp / sqrt(w_sq(1))
```

Unfortunately the procedures lead to totally different results, although mathematically they should be they same.

This whole thing is part of a bigger code and it would be a lot more convenient for me to use the integral version. Originally I tried to double check using the MC simulation and then saw that something must be wrong...

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

For the first piece of code,

> I guess the reason why you have unexpected result is when you are
>   doing the calculations on `hlp`, you try to avoid 0 values, as `0^eta`
>   will blow up - and that is not wanted result, so you simply drop it.
>   But in the last step, `mean(hlp)` will take all values in array `hlp`,
>   including those 0's. Try this:
>
> `mean(hlp(hlp>0))`.
>
> My results fall in roughly 2.x with 10,000-point simulation, 2.3x ~
>   2.4x with 1,000,000 points.

I was wrong. Your problem is you are using too few points. try 10,000,000 points, and you will be satisfied :)

For the second, I have a problem understanding the way you define your variables. (I don't have enough reputations to add a comment, so I put it here. ) Does the "sq" in `w_sq` mean the square root of `w`? Because according to the documentation of [`random`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/random.html), the argument should be "sigma", which is standard deviation. It's natural to define SD as the square root of the variance, which, I guess, is `w`. Then you are doing right in the first piece.

If so, in the second piece of your code, why do you put `sqrt()` on `w_sq`? Do you mean taking a 4th root of the variance? From your definition of expectation, I don't think it's correct. Please take a look at it.

On the other hand, is `w_sq` a single number, or an array?

- If it is a number -

`tmpp / sqrt(w_sq(1))` should be `tmpp / sqrt(w_sq)`, although they don't make difference in fact.

- If it's an array -

You may want to put all codes in a `for` loop. The loop iterates over `w_sq`, each time it picks out one of the elements in the array (name the variable as say `w_sq_elem`), and let the rest of the code do things as if it is a single number.

Anyway, `(log(x)-m)/sqrt(w_sq)` and `tmpp / sqrt(w_sq(1))` are telling different information on `w_sq`. The first one assumes it's a number, so the division can be simply a `/`, rather than `./`. The second one indicates it's an array so you are picking its first element. But an array does not make sense here because, in my understanding, you are not dividing 10,000 points in `x` by 10,000 different variances.

```
m = 3;
w_sq = 2;
eta1 = -2;
ST = random('Lognormal',m,w_sq,10000000,1);
hlp = zeros(10000000,1);
hlp(ST<=2) = ST(ST<=2);
hlp(hlp>0) = hlp(hlp>0).^(eta1+1); % 0^(eta1+1) gives infinity
mean(hlp)

tmpp = integral(@(x) x.^(eta1) .* normpdf((log(x)-m)/w_sq),0,2) ;
tmpp / w_sq

>> untitled

ans =

    0.2944


ans =

    0.2948

>>
```

Comment: Holy smokes, thanks alot for the detailled answer! 

At first, thanks for the note on the documentation of random, I accidentally mixed up standard deviation and variance in my computations. 

Second: In my (longer) code, w_sq is a vector of time dependent variances (_sq denoting 'squared') but I wanted to edit out the index for this example here, since it may cause confusion. Obviously I missed out on some lines and confused you, I apologize. 

All in all, your minimal example showed me that my parameters are the source of the problem. I have m = -0.33, w = .75 (std), eta1 = -8.3375.

Comment: With eta1 I meant eta.. and especially this value of eta messes up the computations and lets the two deviate a lot... As this is now a different problem I thank you loads and we can mark this as solved!

Comment: It has nothing to do with maths, but you may find it useful to avoid naming variables with things like "sq" that could have two different meanings - "squared" or "square root"? People occasionally got trapped by the ambiguity, even if dealing with their own codes (for example, a long time after naming `w_sq` you may forget what you mean).

Comment: Why don't you write `w=.75` and `w2=w^2`? :)